# unable to connect to session id 0 on windows 2012 r2

Tags: windows, session, windows-server-2012-r2, session-0-isolation

I want to connect to session ID=0 on a windows 2012 r2. I have a service which is blocked by a popup (i guess, uac/trust or something). So i need to connect to an interactive session 0 (if possible) to see what is blocking me

of course, mstsc /admin nor mstsc /console works. Neither 'WinStationSwitchToServicesSession' etc..

Any hint ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I find out the solution.

You have to set the key HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows\NoInteractiveServices to 0 then start the service Interactive Services Detection